# ImageClassifierCleaner does not load the widgets

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, fast-ai

After running in my jupyterhub notebook:

```
cleaner = ImageClassifierCleaner(learn)
cleaner
```

result :

`VBox(children=(Dropdown(options=('broccoli', 'kale', 'paprika', 'sugarbeet'), value='broccoli'), Dropdown(opti…`

The GUI widget do not show up, which it make unable to clean the image.

I have tried

1. using alternative to cleaner with [display_image_cleaner](https://forums.fast.ai/t/image-cleaner-doesnt-actually-delete-the-junk-images/80777) -> failed to locate the function
2. updating & reinstalling fastai, fastcore

Question:
Is there any other option to clean up the image files?
Or have I missed something before cleaning

Comment: You could maybe try ImagesCleaner? https://docs.fast.ai/vision.widgets.html#imagescleaner If that doesn't work, try updating your ipywidgets. `pip install --upgrade ipywidgets`

Comment: Thank you ur comment. I check the version and updated it. However Fastcore is now only computable with version <8.0.0. and the widget does not show up